# How do you reference action maps with a player input component?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to make a multiplayer game with unity. I'm using the new input system. My movement uses lamda like this:

`controls.Gameplay.Move.performed += ctx => move = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>();`

This method works fine until I add a second player. Then, both players can be controlled by both controllers. Is there a way access action maps and actions like this using a playerinput component without rewriting most of my code?

I've tried making "controls" into a playerinput class but it throws an error saying that "playerinput does not contain a definition for gameplay"

I've looked all over for a solution but nothing has worked yet. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using:

```
playerInput.actions["Move"].performed += ctx => move = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>();
```

If you need help with this problem, watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZBAr_V7r0M.

Have a nice day!